# Too many arguments error when trying to test for greater than and less than at the same time

Tags: linux, bash

As the tittle states, I just want the line to test if the variable is greater than 10 but less than 30 but it returns an error of "too many arguments"

```
if [ -f myClass ] && grep 'John Smith' myclass > /dev/null

then cat myclass

elif [ -f grades ]

then

grep "s100" grades

elif
[ $ca82 -gt 10 -a $ca82 -lt 30 ]

then
echo "success"

else
echo "test 2"

fi
```

Comment: Your use of `-a` is not wrong. You just need to quote your variable as shown in my answer.

Comment: @perennial_noob extract from shellcheck:` ^-- SC2166: Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.`

Comment: But note that ```The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. ```.  This should be written `[ "$ca82" -gt 10 ] && [ "$ca82" -lt 30 ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
elif [ $ca82 -gt 10 ] && [ $ca82 -lt 30 ]
```

Providing you've set `$ca82` somewhere

Comment: @Nidhoegger edited, but how come?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't export the variable thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the quotes around the variable itself. Rest of it is fine. So:

```
[ "$ca82" -gt 10 -a "$ca82" -lt 30 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if `cat82` is a number but it has an `space` in it. That's why test command complaints of too many arguments.